# Why are there unexplained gaps in chrome dev tools performance tab?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-devtools

99% of my game updates look like this

[image]

but 1% look like this

[image]

`update_gs` is sometimes wasting 6ms doing nothing before calling `mayberender()`!!

i assume these stutters are caused by garbage collection. but the performance tab usually shows GC, there's no GC here. it's just burning 6ms doing nothing!?

in this more zoomed out view you can see the heap memory is climbing during the stutter, so it really shouldn't be GC.

[image]

Comment: Go to devtools settings, experiments panel, enable "V8 runtime stats" and "all events", https://puu.sh/HkySP/7db19c14ba.png

Comment: @wOxxOm solved! put it as an answer https://i.imgur.com/9MEwOzb.png

Comment: JIT compilation was actually my best guess. i was going to mention that but i thought there's no chance it was was stupid enough to block my code while it's trying to run in the main thread to do that. wtf. multi core cpus exist @google